# How to move the above black line to the bottom after the center of the image

Tags: android, kotlin

```
[![UI][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmnT5.png
```

[image]

(How to move the above black line to the bottom after the center of the image)
This is the layout file I am using

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_1"
            style="@style/HorizontalDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"`enter code here`
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_2"
            style="@style/HorizontalDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_close"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/value_30"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_oval_white"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_next"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried with  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" is moving whole view to the end.

Comment: Do you want to move just a blank line? or with center arrow icon?

Comment: Do you want to move the divider_2 to bottom?

Comment: Yes divider 2 to bottom